# Adding text animation to jQuery Slider

Tags: jquery

Most jQuery sliders are just plain image sliders, but I want to add custom text animation such as text sliding.

Now what I would like to ask you is, can I add my own custom text animations without messing up the slider functionality, or is it best to get a full-fletched slider with text animations etc?

Note that I am no expert at jQuery.

Comment: any example? what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: for example: look at this Nivo slider- http://demo.dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/demo-2/. It does not have any text animations such as you see here: http://wordpress.kreatura.hu/layersliderwp/. Now is it possible to add my own to a slider that does not have text effects, or is it best to get/buy one that already has them built in?